# Should I stick to synchronous XML call instead of manipulating an async call?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, browser, fetch

I apologize if the title was vague but I'll try and summarize here.

I've set up an XMML request to an html page to GET the json object that it presents and the code is as follows:

```
        var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhReq.open("GET", 'https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/slug:'+this.props.newCitySlug+'/images/', false);
        xhReq.send(null);
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
        image_url = jsonObject.photos[0].image.web;
```

Everything works well here. However scouring the web; I'm seeing that Synchronous XMLHttpRequest's are deprecated/should not be used/etc. etc.

So I've attempted to establish a fetch api() call as follows

```
fetch('https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/slug:'+this.props.newCitySlug+'/images/')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            image_url = responseData.photos[0].image.web;
})
```

The fetch() api call does work and the code does seem cleaner however my page is rendered prior to the fetch() being complete (i.e. page loads and no image is displayed).

Should I stick with using a synchronous HttpRequest call? Otherwise I'm not sure as to how to use the async fetch() call AND store the data prior to the page loading.

Comment: Short answer: **no**.

Comment: With views dependent on asynchronous fetches, you should use reasonable defaults and placeholders that appear before the data is retrieved from the server

Comment: @MaxSindwani; that makes sense - though once the page loads - its final. Even after the async call is complete - the image doesn't populate itself accordingly (i.e. remains blank).

Comment: Synchronous AJAX is deprecated, so you should avoid it.

Comment: @Iqen Is that the intended behaviour? If not, you should just be able to change the source of the image once the async call completes OR dynamically render the image

Comment: @MaxSindwani That wasn't the intended behaviour but it's structured that way. Not 100% sure how an image (or object) would dynamically change after the page is loaded but I'll scour around and see.

Comment: @Iqen You could try something like https://jsfiddle.net/msindwan/3cvpxtkw/

Comment: @MaxSindwani - setTimeout has no place in asynchronous code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX That's just there to simulate a longer fetch (just to give more time to show the spinner) :P

Comment: ahh, sorry @MaxSindwani - thought you were doing something else :p

Comment: To be honest I can't see how your first piece of code would wait until the image is loaded - you're just assigning an `url` to an (unknown) `var`

Comment: Thanks guys for the input, really appreciate it. Was thinking about this all wrong. I'm building a React app and I just had to configure my async call to appropriately set the state when the component mounts (and the data is received).

And much thanks for the fiddle @MaxSindwani; I'm going to incorporate that as well to give a little 'lag' time.